# ListSFTP state not stored in HBase table for HBase_1_1_2_ClientMapCacheService

Tags: apache-nifi

I have created a HBase_1_1_2_ClientMapCacheService to store state from various ListSFTP processors.  I have created the HBase table into which state should be stored.  After a ListSFTP executes, I scan the table but there are no records in it, yet state is listed for the processor.  Am I wrong to expect there to be a record in the HBase table for state after ListSFTP executes?

Answer (score 0):

A long time ago processors used the distributed map cache to store state, and many of those processors still have the property to support backwards compatibility. Basically if someone upgrades from 0.5 to 1.6, it would attempt to load the old state from DMC and migrate it to the new state management API.

The current approach is that the NiFi framework provides a StateManager to processors which can be used to store state. The state manager being used is configured in state-management.xml.

When you are in standalone NiFi, the state manager is a local write-ahead log, when you are clustered it is ZooKeeper by default, and there is an option for Redis.

If you right click on the processor and select View State you can see whatever state is stored for the processor which will be retrieved from the state manager.

Comment: But he is saying he configured to use `HBase_1_1_2_ClientMapCacheService` so state data should be there in the HBase table, no?

Comment: No the processors do not use the DMC to store state anymore, they only have that property to migrate potential old state, and in fact the property should really have been removed by now because state management was introduced in NiFi 0.5 I believe so we are talking about an unlikely scenario where someone upgrades from 0.4 to latest.